# How to implement gift message form functionality in cart page?

Tags: magento-1.9, giftmessage

I need to implement gift message form functionality in **cart page**. Currently gift message option is available in the **shipping method page** (if gift option enabled in admin). This same functionality  I need to implement in cart page. I used the below [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29819198/add-gift-messages-in-the-billing-information-section-in-magento-checkout) in cart.phtml

```
<div id="onepage-checkout-shipping-method-additional-load">
   <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('checkout/onepage_shipping_method_additional')->setTemplate('checkout/onepage/shipping_method/additional.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
    </div>
```

After using this code gift form showing correctly but the messages are not saving in database properly. Please help me how to handle this.